# Filled errorbars in matplotlib (rectangles)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possibile to make a plot like this in matplotlib? I care only about the red filled rectangles, the crosses are easily done with `errorbar`.

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `errorbar` can't do this, but you can create a `PatchCollection` from your error data which can easily be added to the axes. See this quick script for an example of how you could do this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# Number of data points
n=5

# Dummy data
x=np.arange(0,n,1)
y=np.random.rand(n)*5.

# Dummy errors (above and below)
xerr=np.random.rand(2,n)
yerr=np.random.rand(2,n)

# Create figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Plot data points
ax.errorbar(x,y,xerr=xerr,yerr=yerr,fmt='None',ecolor='k')

# Function to plot error boxes
def makeErrorBoxes(xdata,ydata,xerror,yerror,fc='r',ec='None',alpha=0.5):

    # Create list for all the error patches
    errorboxes = []

    # Loop over data points; create box from errors at each point
    for xc,yc,xe,ye in zip(xdata,ydata,xerror.T,yerror.T):
        rect = Rectangle((xc-xe[0],yc-ye[0]),xe.sum(),ye.sum())
        errorboxes.append(rect)

    # Create patch collection with specified colour/alpha
    pc = PatchCollection(errorboxes,facecolor=fc,alpha=alpha,edgecolor=ec)

    # Add collection to axes
    ax.add_collection(pc)

# Call function to create error boxes
makeErrorBoxes(x,y,xerr,yerr)

# Add some space around the data points on the axes
ax.margins(0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @tcaswell: Sure. I think I've done it (in `examples/statistics`), but I'm new to git so please let me know if I've done anything wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Drawing squares is really easy with `matplotlib.patches`, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import matplotlib.patches

pl.figure()
ax = pl.gca()
ax.add_patch(
   matplotlib.patches.Rectangle(
       (1.0, 1.0), # x, y
       2.0,        # width
       2.0,        # height
       color='r', alpha=0.5
   ) )
ax.set_aspect(1)

pl.xlim(0,4)
pl.ylim(0,4)
```

[image]

Comment: drawing one square is really easy... I hoped there was a simpler method so say to `errorbar`: "draw rectangles"

Comment: Ah, like that. Sorry, then I misinterpreted your question

Comment: Then I would probably just write a small wrapper function for `pl.errorbar` to automate the combination of error bar + rectangle