# Filled error bars in Python Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, rectangles

I saw this question to do with matplotlib here:

[Filled errorbars in matplotlib (rectangles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852462/filled-errorbars-in-matplotlib-rectangles/37852631)

I was wondering if something like this is possible in Plotly?

To be specific, I want to know whether you can take a "Scatter" graph object and fill the error bars with a rectangle, as in the following image:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing it but you can just add `shapes` in your `layout`.

Let's assume the errors are a two dimensional list:

```
errors = {'x': [[0.1, 0.4],
                [0.2, 0.3],
                [0.3, 0.2],
                [0.4, 0.1],
                [0.45, 0.05]
               ],
          'y': [[0.4, 0.1],
                [0.3, 0.2],
                [0.2, 0.3],
                [0.1, 0.4],
                [0.05, 0.45]]}
```

Now we create a rectangle `shape` for each error:

```
shapes = list()
for i in range(len(errors['x'])):
    shapes.append({'x0': points['x'][i] - errors['x'][i][0],
                   'y0': points['y'][i] - errors['y'][i][0],
                   'x1': points['x'][i] + errors['x'][i][1],
                   'y1': points['y'][i] + errors['y'][i][1],
                   'fillcolor': 'rgb(160, 0, 0)',
                   'layer': 'below',
                   'line': {'width': 0}
                  })
layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(shapes=shapes)
```

[image]

The asymmetric error bars are created via `'symmetric': False`

**Complete code**

```
points = {'x': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
          'y': [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]}
errors = {'x': [[0.1, 0.4],
                [0.2, 0.3],
                [0.3, 0.2],
                [0.4, 0.1],
                [0.45, 0.05]
               ],
          'y': [[0.4, 0.1],
                [0.3, 0.2],
                [0.2, 0.3],
                [0.1, 0.4],
                [0.05, 0.45]]}

scatter = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=points['x'],
                                    y=points['y'],
                                    error_x={'type': 'data',
                                             'array': [e[1] for e in errors['x']],
                                             'arrayminus': [e[0] for e in errors['x']],
                                             'symmetric': False
                                            },
                                    error_y={'type': 'data',
                                             'array': [e[1] for e in errors['y']],
                                             'arrayminus': [e[0] for e in errors['y']],
                                             'symmetric': False
                                            },                                    
                                    mode='markers')
shapes = list()
for i in range(len(errors['x'])):
    shapes.append({'x0': points['x'][i] - errors['x'][i][0],
                   'y0': points['y'][i] - errors['y'][i][0],
                   'x1': points['x'][i] + errors['x'][i][1],
                   'y1': points['y'][i] + errors['y'][i][1],
                   'fillcolor': 'rgb(160, 0, 0)',
                   'layer': 'below',
                   'line': {'width': 0}
                  })
layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(shapes=shapes)
data = plotly.graph_objs.Data([scatter], error_x=[e[0] for e in errors['x']])
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! However, is there any way to somehow incorporate the rectangle to the legend, so that the trace can be correctly identified?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `shapes` and `traces` are independent in `Plotly`, so if you toggle a trace the shape does not disappear.