# is it possible to display figures on a graph with matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Is there a function in Matplotlib to display black rectangles on a graphic ?, like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into Matplotlib's **Patches** and subsequent **Rectangle** modulus. Here's an [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/errorbars_and_boxes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-errorbars-and-boxes-py) showcasing box creations with some error bars.

Comment: interesting, I just tested, it should do the trick! In the meantime, I found another simpler [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37852631/13517638) than that of the Matplotlib documentation for drawing error boxes. I think I should get something done with both. thanks